# return type for redux root reducer

Tags: typescript, redux, connected-react-router

I am convert my root reducer from javascript to typescript, however, I am getting a linting error saying:

> Missing return type on function.
>   (@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type)

What should be the proper return type for my root reducer function? Thanks.

```
import { History } from 'history';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { connectRouter } from 'connected-react-router';
import sampleReducer from './sampleReducer';

export default (historyObject: History) => combineReducers({
  sampleReducer,
  router: connectRouter(historyObject),
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you've set the rule "[Require explicit return types on functions and class methods](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/explicit-function-return-type.md)" and you're required to specify return types for functions explicitly.

combineReducer [return function](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/e67f14d4c54bd6218dca54847c981b480a438cc6/index.d.ts#L93) of type [`Reducer<S, A>`](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/e67f14d4c54bd6218dca54847c981b480a438cc6/index.d.ts#L61), where `S` is standing for app state.

First of all I suggest you to define app state like below

```
import { RouterState } from 'connected-react-router';

type AppState = {
    sampleReducer: /* type of state, that sampleReducer accepts and returns */;
    router: RouterState
}
```

Then you'll be able to type root reducer

```
import { Reducer } from 'redux';

export default (historyObject: History): Reducer<AppState> => combineReducers({
    sampleReducer,
    router: connectRouter(historyObject),
});
```